# Getting error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in FBRectNativeSpec" during ios build for react-native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

I have a React-Native application, which runs perfectly on Android.

When I'm trying to build and run the application for iOS I am getting the following error:

`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code` `in FBReactSpec`

I also tried these solutions https://dev.to/glocore/react-native-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-of9 and https://kdshah6593.medium.com/solution-to-phase-script-execution-error-react-native-27fc6b709915 but luckily doesn't work.

**Environment**

```
macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
XCode version 12.4 (12D4e)
node v14.17.4
```

let me know if anyone have solution regarding this.

Thanks for your time viewing my question.